# Rudin's Principles of Analysis Theorem 1.11

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I'm having a problem with this theorem. What if set $B$ is all $x$ such that $\sqrt{2} < x \le 2$, and $S$ is the set of all $y$ such that $\sqrt{2} < y \le 3$. $\sup L = \sqrt{2}$, which does not exist in $S$. Does this prove the theorem wrong by contradiction?

---

**1.11 Theorem** Suppose $S$ is an ordered set with the least-upper-bound property, $B \subset S$, $B$ is not empty, and $B$ is bounded below. Let $L$ be the set of all lower bounds of $B$. Then $\alpha = \sup L$ exists in $S$, and $\alpha = \inf B$.

Comment: It would be better to state the theorem in this space. Many viewers, including some who could give very good answers, will not have the book at hand.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102874/rudin-theorem-1-11

Comment: ... and I do have the book, but apparently a different edition (mine is Second Edition), because Theorem 1.11 in mine is about the $<$ relation on Dedekind cuts.

Comment: There is a exercise in Rudin related to this, although I forget what chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your example does not meet the hypotheses of the theorem, because $B$ is not bounded below in $S$.  Note that $L=\{a\in S:\text{for all }b\in B, a\leq b\}=\emptyset$.

Comment: Is there a reason why you make some of your answers community wiki?

Comment: @Marvis: Sometimes I feel like doing so. This is more common when I have very little to say.  Others are welcome to edit.

Comment: First, what is "bounded below in L"?, and second: this is not what the theorem states, but merely "bounded below", which it is.

Comment: @DonAntonio: The ordered set in which bounds are considered is $S$ (not $L$, and in the context of the OP's example, not $\mathbb R$).  While the statement of the theorem would perhaps be clearer if "in $S$" were explicitly stated for emphasis, in this context $S$ is the "universe".  The most common application is where $S=\mathbb R$, but Rudin's statement abstracts the essential order properties, and the OP's example does not satisfy those properties.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks

Comment: Thank you Jonas for your explanation and DonAntonio for your question. This was very helpful.